# How to make Hive UDFs defined using the spark Interface show up in the SHOW FUNCTIONS list?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, apache-spark

I am trying to register a Hive UDF. Compare the following two approaches:

**Using the spark interface**

```scala
sqlContext.registerFunction( "foobar",  ( s : String ) => "foobar" )
```

**Using the hive interface**

```scala
@Description(
  name = "foobar",
  value = "_FUNC_(str) - foobars the string",
  extended = "Example:\n" +
             "  foobar('baz') == 'foobar' "
  )
class FooBarFunction extends UDF
{
  def evaluate(s : Text) : Text = new Text("foobar")
}

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION foobar AS 'my.package.path.FooBarFunction'")
```

I would like to use the Spark interface which is much more convenient, especially when it comes to defining aggregations.
However, there are two (related) things that I could not figure out:

1. UDFs defined using "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION" show up in the list generated by "SHOW FUNCTIONS". UDFs defined using the spark interface don't. Can I register the function somehow so that it does show up in the list?
2. I did not find a way to add a description to the function registered using the spark interface like I did with the `@Description` annotation. Is there any way to add this documentation?